# Connecting an SQL database to C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having a little problem with SQL, where it says "public Form1(); at the very top of the code, according to the begginers guide I'm following there should be a little box with 3 dots in it (like this [...]) instead of ";"

```
public Form1();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

            con.ConnectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Wee                                                                    Jimmy\\Documents\\MyWorkers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

            con.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("Open");

            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Closed");
```

Please can someone help I'm ready to throw the towel in. The error says, Error  1   'SQL_Connection.Form1.Form1()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial    C:\Users\Wee Jimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SQL Connection\SQL Connection\Form1.cs 15  16  SQL Connection

Comment: `[...]` means <more code is here, you can't just copy-paste this>.  Try copying just the part in Form1_Load into your code.

Comment: Is this all fo the code?

Comment: I would have expected something like public class Form1{ }  or if that is a constructor, public Form1(){}

Comment: Wait a minute, I suggest you actually learn C# before trying to plug it with a database.

Comment: I strongly agree with @EtiennedeMartel

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I disagree. Connecting to the database is valid as an excercise as anything else.

Comment: @LukeP Sure, but if you can't even write code that is _syntactically valid_, then connecting to a database is going to be the least of your problems.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel the poster is clearly trying to follow the instructions in a tutorial that he misunderstands or the tutorial is crap.  I vote for the latter.  Jim Mcmurtry, is the beginner's guide available online so you can show us exactly what it looks like.  "public Form1();" is syntactically completely bollixed up.  It won't even compile let alone run.  It even looks painful.

Comment: [...] is usually a collapsed region or section of code in the IDE view, there is usually a + sigh next to it to "unfold" that section again

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I see your point. I'd say that learning basics of C# before trying to access the database would be recommended

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've editedt he code above to show the error, the tut I'm following is on this page http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p3.html, @EtiennedeMartel, I've followed that entire website, I've done lots of practise, this is just too difficult for me at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line:

```
public Form1();
```

to:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: The InitializeComponent(); part is underlined in red, I've tried this too.

Comment: @JimMcmurtry: It sounds like you got yourself into a pickle. Try creating a new form from scratch: from the Project menu, select Add New Form... this should create form2 for you. Then you can copy your SQL code from the old form. You will also need to set the new form as your startup form: In Program.cs, change  Application.Run(new Form1()); to  Application.Run(new Form2());

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel the error is on the bottom of my original post, 'SQL_Connection.Form1.Form1()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial C:\Users\Wee Jimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SQL Connection\SQL Connection\Form1.cs 15 16 SQL Connection did you have a look at the tutorial to see if I missed anything? http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
public Form1()
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con; 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(); 

        con.ConnectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Wee Jimmy\\Documents\\MyWorkers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"; 

        con.Open(); 

        MessageBox.Show("Open"); 

        con.Close(); 

        MessageBox.Show("Closed"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That answer is not syntactically valid.  There is no class definition, you can't declare a method inside another method, and even if you fixed the definition the "Form1_Load" wouldn't fire because it has to be added to the event (usually done in the designer).